# Joining two select statements and aligning them

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm have one table that looks like this:

```
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
| ENTRY_ID  | EMPLOYEE_ID  |      ACCESS_TIME    |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
|   001     |     1001     | 6/3/2014 8:08:00 AM |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
|   777     |     1201     | 8/3/2015 7:07:00 AM |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
|   888     |     1901     | 9/9/2015 4:04:00 PM |
+-----------+--------------+---------------------+
```

In order to get the number of unique users for a particular date range, I have the following code:

```
SELECT COUNT(UNIQUE Employee_Id) Unique_Monthly_Users FROM 
    (SELECT * FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
        WHERE ACCESS_TIME  >= TO_DATE('8/1/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        AND ACCESS_TIME  < TO_DATE('9/1/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ORDER BY ACCESS_TIME ASC)
```

And to get the current month for that range, I'm using this:

```
SELECT UNIQUE TO_CHAR(ACCESS_TIME, 'Month') Month_Name FROM (
    SELECT * FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
        WHERE ACCESS_TIME  >= TO_DATE('8/1/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
        AND ACCESS_TIME  < TO_DATE('9/1/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ORDER BY ACCESS_TIME ASC)
```

Here's my final desired output:

```
+--------------+-----------+
| UNIQUE_USERS |   MONTH   |
+--------------+-----------+
|  702931      |  JANUARY  |
+--------------+-----------+
|  900000      |  FEBRUARY |
+--------------+-----------+
|  2139041022  |  MARCH    |
+--------------+-----------+
```

Now I've tried to join these statements:

```
SELECT COUNT(UNIQUE EMPLOYEE_ID) Unique_Emp FROM 
    ((SELECT * FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
          WHERE ACCESS_TIME  >= TO_DATE('8/1/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
          AND ACCESS_TIME  < TO_DATE('9/1/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
      ORDER BY ACCESS_TIME ASC) col1) 
INNER JOIN (SELECT UNIQUE TO_CHAR(ACCESS_TIME, 'Month') Month_Name FROM (
    (SELECT * FROM CORE.DATE_TEST
         WHERE ACCESS_TIME  >= TO_DATE('8/1/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
         AND ACCESS_TIME  < TO_DATE('9/1/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
    ORDER BY ACCESS_TIME ASC
    ) col2)
 ) ON COL1.ENTRY_ID = COL2.ENTRY_ID
```

...but obviously this will not work. I am not able to get the "id" because there should not be an ID for either result set. Both are collections which exist outside. I get the following error: `ORA-00904: "COL2"."ENTRY_ID": invalid identifier`

How do I properly join these result sets so I can get the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look up the `GROUP BY` clause and then try this:

```
select to_char(access_time, 'Month'), count(distinct employee_id)
from core.date_test
where usage_time >= TO_DATE('8/1/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
and usage_time < TO_DATE('9/1/2015 00:00:00', 'MM/DD/YYYY HH24:MI:SS')
group by to_char(access_time, 'Month');
```

Comment: Heh... and to think I almost had this, but forgot to add a `GROUP BY`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with two clauses, the first one selected distinct users for each month and the second one counts them:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(*) AS UNIQUE_USERS,
    T1.MONTH
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        USER_ID,
        TO_CHAR(ACCESS_TIME) AS MONTH
    FROM DATE_TEST
) AS T1
GROUP BY T1.MONTH
```

Comment: This requires modification under PLSQL. For instance, you have to remove the `AS` keyword before `T1`. Also, it returns DD-MM-YY, which is not the format I want it to be. Finally, you'll have to change `TO_CHAR(ACCESS_TIME)` to `TO_CHAR(ACCESS_TIME, 'Month')` for it to output correctly. Good alternative, though. Thanks!